# Azure Function - Trigger blob storage copy when last modified

Tags: azure, function, azure-blob-storage

First time working with azure functions. In my run.csx i have

```
public static void Run(Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
}
```

and in my functions.json i have

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myBlob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "insights-logs-auditlogs/{name}",
      "connection": "stnhnmspsplunkmgmt_STORAGE"
    },
    {
      "name": "Output",
      "path": "test/{rand-guid}",
      "connection": "sttestfuncapptest_STORAGE",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "blob"
    }
  ]
}
```

This works fine when i edit existing files in the containers, but i cant figure out how to do the copy when a change has happened. Anyone can point me in the right direction. Greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question. "This works fine when i edit existing files", "can't figure out when a change has happened". When someone edits an existing file, it's a change that had happened.

Answer (score 0):

The Blob storage trigger starts a function when a new or updated blob is detected .
As [this blob trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp#example) for azure function writes a log when a blob is added or updated in the samples-workitems container.

Try to create a SAS URL for the blob with required permissions with minimum read  and then use that for file copy in c# and publish in azure.

Please check this [SO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69216133/azure-function-blob-trigger-copy-file-to-file-share)

```
[FunctionName("MyBlobTrigger")]
public async void Run([BlobTrigger("uploads/{name}", Connection = "UploadStorageAccount")]CloudBlockBlob myBlob, string name, ILogger log, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

    // Get SAS for the blob
    var sasToken = myBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature();
    
    //SAS URI
    var blobSasUrl = $"{myBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri}{sasToken}";

    ShareClient share = new ShareClient(storageConnection, fileShareName);

    ShareDirectoryClient directory = share.GetRootDirectoryClient();
    ShareFileClient fileShare = directory.GetFileClient(name);

    ShareClient share = new ShareClient(storageConnection, fileShareName);

    ShareDirectoryClient directory = share.GetRootDirectoryClient();
    ShareFileClient fileShare = directory.GetFileClient(name);

    try
    {
        
        fileShare.Create(myBlob.Properties.Length);
       
 //Copy blob's contents to storage file using async file copy.
        //await fileShare.StartCopyAsync(new Uri(blobSasUrl));
    }
}
```

**Other references:**

1. [c# - Azure Function Blob Trigger copy file to File Share - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69216133/azure-function-blob-trigger-copy-file-to-file-share)
2. [ADF: copy last modified blob - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/349584/adf-copy-last-modified-blob.html) / [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/solution-template-copy-new-files-lastmodifieddate)
3. [LastModifiedDate with Azure Data Factory | Azure Blog and Updates | Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/incrementally-copy-new-files-by-lastmodifieddate-with-azure-data-factory/)